# Traveling with EU spouse to his home country with expired residence card

Tags: resident-permit, eu-spouses

I'm a non-EU married to EU citizen in France overseas. I have a temporary residence card from his home country but it's few weeks expired and I exceeded my 3 months stay in France overseas. My question is: as we want to go back to his home country, is it possible for me to travel there with our marriage certificate and the expired residence card and valid passport? Or will I have problems gaining entry?

Comment: Do you normally require a visa for the Schengen Area? If yes, such a visa will be issued free of charge and swiftly.

Comment: Yes i do. But i wanted to apply for a renewal to my card when i get back to his country of origins. So for the visa application i should do it in the ambassy right?

Comment: In theory, when traveling together with the expired card and marriage certificate, a refusal at the port of entry is unlikely. The airline, however, may not let you board the plane. Getting the visa would avoid all of these problems.